# Postback Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wonder why if anyone has idea of this error?
My ASP.Net page was working fine when publish on my Win7 IIS7 and on another Server 2008 IIS7, but today when I do the same one for another Server 2008, all the ajax postback gives this error:

```
#Exception Message: 
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.office_desktop_wlogin_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\paradigmasp\77933d43\29398497\App_Web_npn2130s.2.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I wonder what will be the possible reason for the error?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You've given us the trace but not the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked through all of the settings to make sure the sites are setup exactly the same? I think the main two things I would look at are:

AppPool - make sure both of the sites are using the same version of .NET in the app pool
Directory Permissions - check the directory to make sure IIS can access it

Does the site run correctly other than the AJAX requests?